# Resize Full image not work in opencart 2

Tags: opencart, image-resizing, opencart2.x

I Work with opencart 2.1.0.1. When I upload image see all image have a `space`/`background` and not resize image to new size.

Original image:

[image]

After Upload and resize to 185x185 :

[image]

I need to resize width/height to new size IE:185*185. How do can I resize image Like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your image to `185*185` in a tool like `paint`, and then upload it.
or in opencart set dimensions to `185*134`, to prevent opencart adding spaces, then use css: `width: 100%;` for `img`